# sql server conditional select into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, conditional-statements, temp-tables

I'm working in SQL Server 2008, and I'm trying to select into a temp table based on a certain condition...for a report, I need **up to** 18% of the records to be of a certain product type.

```
if ((@totalRecords * .18) > @productTypeCount)
    select * into #tmpLP_REIT
    from myTable where productType = @productType
else
    select top 18 percent * into #tmpLP_REIT
    from myTable where productType = @productType
```

I keep getting error "there is already an object named '#tmpLP_REIT' in the database" even though I know it isn't there because when I try to drop such table, it points out it doesn't exist. **I also get this error on the else clause.**

It seems it's ignoring my if statement and going right through creating the first table, then trying to create it again. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code in a loop?..  that would explain the error if it were happening the second time though.  If not, the syntax checker must just be choking because it sees 2 queries creating the same table, not realizing it is a conditional.

One solution would be to create the table first, and then change the syntax of those 2 queries to `insert into` queries.

Another solution would be to use dynamic SQL... build the right query in the conditional, and then execute it afterwards.  This should get passed the validation you're currently triggering.

Comment: The reason I was trying to avoid this was because this is only the first of a number of tables I'll end up creating...rather sizable tables, so select into would cut a lot of code and effort :)

Comment: @Gio ahh..  well I added another possibility to my answer.   Also, you didn't mention if it was in a loop or not?

Comment: oh yeah sorry, not in a loop.

Comment: Sorry these really are your only options. It is a bad practice to use selct into anyway as you have no control over datatypes.

Comment: @HLGEM. I question your comment. I think the resulting col data are completley predictable and cobntrollable and furthermore, I would argue that using a SELECT INTO may be more resilient to table data type changes.